# How to stop re login the application with browser back button?

Tags: javascript, extjs

My application is running in a tab in the browser window. Now if I write some other URL in the same tab say www.google.com and press enter to open this. Now in my tab google.com is opened.

Now if I press the browser's back button, it takes me to my application in the login state.
Ideally it should logout from the application and should show the login page, if it is redirected back to my application with the browser's back button. Please suggest the suitable solution.

I'm using extjs as the front end technology.

Comment: Consider using `beforeunload` event.

Comment: [Java is to Javascript as Ham is to Hamster](http://www.devbattles.com/en/images/upload/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8ad-1.jpg)

Comment: I tried using `beforeunload` but it opens a default pop up window which has two buttons,_leave the page_ and _cancel_ . I tried to capture the event of these button click but could not do that....... :(